# Android Fullscreen Dialog padding issue on marshmallow

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out hw to remove padding from FUllscreen dialog

below is styles which we are using while creating dialog object :

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>

        <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>

        <!-- Just to prove it's working -->
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    </style>
```

below is the dialog content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout1"
        >

        <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:cropAspectRatioX="5"
            app:cropAspectRatioY="5"
            app:cropShape="oval" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#a9aeac"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#a9aeac"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How to remove padding i have set the style but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the codes:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_content);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
can you try set layouts without style class in xml file?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_school_schoolname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/collegename"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_school_schoolweb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/collegeweb"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_school_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```